# Make table of object in PHP for JSON return

Tags: php, json, rss

I'm using this script in order to make json :

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$feed = new DOMDocument();
$feed->load("http://www.feedforall.com/sample.xml");
//$feed->load($_GET['url']);
$json = array();

$json['title'] =  $feed->getElementsByTagName('channel')->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->firstChild->nodeValue;
$json['description'] = $feed->getElementsByTagName('channel')->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->firstChild->nodeValue;
$json['link'] =  $feed->getElementsByTagName('channel')->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->firstChild->nodeValue;

$items = $feed->getElementsByTagName('channel')->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('item');

$json['item'] = array();
$i = 0;


foreach($items as $item) {

   $title =  $item->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->firstChild->nodeValue;
   $description = $item->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->firstChild->nodeValue;
   $pubDate = $item->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->firstChild->nodeValue;
   $guid = $item->getElementsByTagName('guid')->item(0)->firstChild->nodeValue;

   $json['item'][$i++]['title'] = $title;
   $json['item'][$i++]['description'] = $description;
   $json['item'][$i++]['pubdate'] = $pubDate;
   $json['item'][$i++]['guid'] = $guid;   

}


echo json_encode($json);


?>
```

In the foreach loop, it takes all the item of the feed one by one and put them in item php table.

When I return, there is no table, all item properties are sent flat:

```
{
    "title": "FeedForAll Sample Feed",
    "description": "RSS is a fascinating technology. The uses for RSS are expanding daily. Take a closer look at how various industries are using the benefits of RSS in their businesses.",
    "link": "http://www.feedforall.com/industry-solutions.htm",
    "item": [
        {
            "title": "RSS Solutions for Restaurants"
        },
        {
            "description": "<b>FeedForAll </b>helps Restaurant's communicate with customers. Let your customers know the latest specials or events.<br>\n<br>\nRSS feed uses include:<br>\n<i><font color=\"#FF0000\">Daily Specials <br>\nEntertainment <br>\nCalendar of Events </i></font>"
        },
        {},
        {},
        {
            "title": "RSS Solutions for Schools and Colleges"
        },
        {
            "description": "FeedForAll helps Educational Institutions communicate with students about school wide activities, events, and schedules.<br>\n<br>\nRSS feed uses include:<br>\n<i><font color=\"#0000FF\">Homework Assignments <br>\nSchool Cancellations <br>\nCalendar of Events <br>\nSports Scores <br>\nClubs/Organization Meetings <br>\nLunches Menus </i></font>"
        },
        {
            "pubdate": "Tue, 19 Oct 2004 11:09:09 -0400"
        },
        {
            "guid": null
        },
        {
            "title": "RSS Solutions for Computer Service Companies"
        },
        {
            "description": "FeedForAll helps Computer Service Companies communicate with clients about cyber security and related issues. <br>\n<br>\nUses include:<br>\n<i><font color=\"#0000FF\">Cyber Security Alerts <br>\nSpecials<br>\nJob Postings </i></font>"
        },
        {
            "pubdate": "Tue, 19 Oct 2004 11:09:07 -0400"
        },
        {
            "guid": null
        },
        {
            "title": "RSS Solutions for Governments"
        },
        {
            "description": "FeedForAll helps Governments communicate with the general public about positions on various issues, and keep the community aware of changes in important legislative issues. <b><i><br>\n</b></i><br>\nRSS uses Include:<br>\n<i><font color=\"#00FF00\">Legislative Calendar<br>\nVotes<br>\nBulletins</i></font>"
        },
        {
            "pubdate": "Tue, 19 Oct 2004 11:09:05 -0400"
        },
        {
            "guid": null
        },
        {
            "title": "RSS Solutions for Politicians"
        },
        {
            "description": "FeedForAll helps Politicians communicate with the general public about positions on various issues, and keep the community notified of their schedule. <br>\n<br>\nUses Include:<br>\n<i><font color=\"#FF0000\">Blogs<br>\nSpeaking Engagements <br>\nStatements<br>\n </i></font>"
        },
        {
            "pubdate": "Tue, 19 Oct 2004 11:09:03 -0400"
        },
        {
            "guid": null
        },
        {
            "title": "RSS Solutions for Meteorologists"
        },
        {
            "description": "FeedForAll helps Meteorologists communicate with the general public about storm warnings and weather alerts, in specific regions. Using RSS meteorologists are able to quickly disseminate urgent and life threatening weather warnings. <br>\n<br>\nUses Include:<br>\n<i><font color=\"#0000FF\">Weather Alerts<br>\nPlotting Storms<br>\nSchool Cancellations </i></font>"
        },
        {
            "pubdate": "Tue, 19 Oct 2004 11:09:01 -0400"
        },
        {
            "guid": null
        },
        {
            "title": "RSS Solutions for Realtors & Real Estate Firms"
        },
        {
            "description": "FeedForAll helps Realtors and Real Estate companies communicate with clients informing them of newly available properties, and open house announcements. RSS helps to reach a targeted audience and spread the word in an inexpensive, professional manner. <font color=\"#0000FF\"><br>\n</font><br>\nFeeds can be used for:<br>\n<i><font color=\"#FF0000\">Open House Dates<br>\nNew Properties For Sale<br>\nMortgage Rates</i></font>"
        },
        {
            "pubdate": "Tue, 19 Oct 2004 11:08:59 -0400"
        },
        {
            "guid": null
        },
        {
            "title": "RSS Solutions for Banks / Mortgage Companies"
        },
        {
            "description": "FeedForAll helps <b>Banks, Credit Unions and Mortgage companies</b> communicate with the general public about rate changes in a prompt and professional manner. <br>\n<br>\nUses include:<br>\n<i><font color=\"#0000FF\">Mortgage Rates<br>\nForeign Exchange Rates <br>\nBank Rates<br>\nSpecials</i></font>"
        },
        {
            "pubdate": "Tue, 19 Oct 2004 11:08:57 -0400"
        },
        {
            "guid": null
        },
        {
            "title": "RSS Solutions for Law Enforcement"
        },
        {
            "description": "<b>FeedForAll</b> helps Law Enforcement Professionals communicate with the general public and other agencies in a prompt and efficient manner. Using RSS police are able to quickly disseminate urgent and life threatening information. <br>\n<br>\nUses include:<br>\n<i><font color=\"#0000FF\">Amber Alerts<br>\nSex Offender Community Notification <br>\nWeather Alerts <br>\nScheduling <br>\nSecurity Alerts <br>\nPolice Report <br>\nMeetings</i></font>"
        },
        {
            "pubdate": "Tue, 19 Oct 2004 11:08:56 -0400"
        },
        {
            "guid": null
        }
    ]
}
```

So What is the mistake? I was thinking that the fact to put tables in item should work but apparently not :-/ How Can I make them looks more like items in this one?

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "feed": {
        "url": "http://www.feedforall.com/sample.xml",
        "title": "FeedForAll Sample Feed",
        "link": "http://www.feedforall.com/industry-solutions.htm",
        "author": "",
        "description": "RSS is a fascinating technology. The uses for RSS are expanding daily. Take a closer look at how various industries are using the benefits of RSS in their businesses.",
        "image": "http://www.feedforall.com/ffalogo48x48.gif"
    },
    "items": [
        {
            "title": "RSS Solutions for Restaurants",
            "pubDate": "2004-10-19 15:09:11",
            "link": "http://www.feedforall.com/restaurant.htm",
            "guid": "db4b074250d7eedba34de1c872724ebd",
            "author": "",
            "thumbnail": "",
            "description": "\n<b>FeedForAll </b>helps Restaurant's communicate with customers. Let your customers know the latest specials or events.<br><br>\nRSS feed uses include:<br><i>Daily Specials <br>\nEntertainment <br>\nCalendar of Events </i>\n",
            "content": "\n<b>FeedForAll </b>helps Restaurant's communicate with customers. Let your customers know the latest specials or events.<br><br>\nRSS feed uses include:<br><i>Daily Specials <br>\nEntertainment <br>\nCalendar of Events </i>\n",
            "enclosure": [],
            "categories": [
                "Computers/Software/Internet/Site Management/Content Management"
            ]
        },
        {
            "title": "RSS Solutions for Schools and Colleges",
            "pubDate": "2004-10-19 15:09:09",
            "link": "http://www.feedforall.com/schools.htm",
            "guid": "315ce482517f7e1d2d50f5a68d0e64fc",
            "author": "",
            "thumbnail": "",
            "description": "FeedForAll helps Educational Institutions communicate with students about school wide activities, events, and schedules.<br><br>\nRSS feed uses include:<br><i>Homework Assignments <br>\nSchool Cancellations <br>\nCalendar of Events <br>\nSports Scores <br>\nClubs/Organization Meetings <br>\nLunches Menus </i>\n",
            "content": "FeedForAll helps Educational Institutions communicate with students about school wide activities, events, and schedules.<br><br>\nRSS feed uses include:<br><i>Homework Assignments <br>\nSchool Cancellations <br>\nCalendar of Events <br>\nSports Scores <br>\nClubs/Organization Meetings <br>\nLunches Menus </i>\n",
            "enclosure": [],
            "categories": [
                "Computers/Software/Internet/Site Management/Content Management"
            ]
        },
        {
            "title": "RSS Solutions for Computer Service Companies",
            "pubDate": "2004-10-19 15:09:07",
            "link": "http://www.feedforall.com/computer-service.htm",
            "guid": "7973f3583dd2e760f6e1385a90cf87a8",
            "author": "",
            "thumbnail": "",
            "description": "FeedForAll helps Computer Service Companies communicate with clients about cyber security and related issues. <br><br>\nUses include:<br><i>Cyber Security Alerts <br>\nSpecials<br>\nJob Postings </i>\n",
            "content": "FeedForAll helps Computer Service Companies communicate with clients about cyber security and related issues. <br><br>\nUses include:<br><i>Cyber Security Alerts <br>\nSpecials<br>\nJob Postings </i>\n",
            "enclosure": [],
            "categories": [
                "Computers/Software/Internet/Site Management/Content Management"
            ]
        },
        {
            "title": "RSS Solutions for Governments",
            "pubDate": "2004-10-19 15:09:05",
            "link": "http://www.feedforall.com/government.htm",
            "guid": "d6131efb3d938b112ab861b97434942a",
            "author": "",
            "thumbnail": "",
            "description": "FeedForAll helps Governments communicate with the general public about positions on various issues, and keep the community aware of changes in important legislative issues. <b><i><br></i></b><br>\nRSS uses Include:<br><i>Legislative Calendar<br>\nVotes<br>\nBulletins</i>\n",
            "content": "FeedForAll helps Governments communicate with the general public about positions on various issues, and keep the community aware of changes in important legislative issues. <b><i><br></i></b><br>\nRSS uses Include:<br><i>Legislative Calendar<br>\nVotes<br>\nBulletins</i>\n",
            "enclosure": [],
            "categories": [
                "Computers/Software/Internet/Site Management/Content Management"
            ]
        },
        {
            "title": "RSS Solutions for Politicians",
            "pubDate": "2004-10-19 15:09:03",
            "link": "http://www.feedforall.com/politics.htm",
            "guid": "d01522b2d34449e665339b1c64500492",
            "author": "",
            "thumbnail": "",
            "description": "FeedForAll helps Politicians communicate with the general public about positions on various issues, and keep the community notified of their schedule. <br><br>\nUses Include:<br><i>Blogs<br>\nSpeaking Engagements <br>\nStatements<br></i>\n",
            "content": "FeedForAll helps Politicians communicate with the general public about positions on various issues, and keep the community notified of their schedule. <br><br>\nUses Include:<br><i>Blogs<br>\nSpeaking Engagements <br>\nStatements<br></i>\n",
            "enclosure": [],
            "categories": [
                "Computers/Software/Internet/Site Management/Content Management"
            ]
        },
        {
            "title": "RSS Solutions for Meteorologists",
            "pubDate": "2004-10-19 15:09:01",
            "link": "http://www.feedforall.com/weather.htm",
            "guid": "5273191196b584a4c5a98017d5a1b1d6",
            "author": "",
            "thumbnail": "",
            "description": "FeedForAll helps Meteorologists communicate with the general public about storm warnings and weather alerts, in specific regions. Using RSS meteorologists are able to quickly disseminate urgent and life threatening weather warnings. <br><br>\nUses Include:<br><i>Weather Alerts<br>\nPlotting Storms<br>\nSchool Cancellations </i>\n",
            "content": "FeedForAll helps Meteorologists communicate with the general public about storm warnings and weather alerts, in specific regions. Using RSS meteorologists are able to quickly disseminate urgent and life threatening weather warnings. <br><br>\nUses Include:<br><i>Weather Alerts<br>\nPlotting Storms<br>\nSchool Cancellations </i>\n",
            "enclosure": [],
            "categories": [
                "Computers/Software/Internet/Site Management/Content Management"
            ]
        },
        {
            "title": "RSS Solutions for Realtors &amp; Real Estate Firms",
            "pubDate": "2004-10-19 15:08:59",
            "link": "http://www.feedforall.com/real-estate.htm",
            "guid": "ce3eb8e9a2370c05babd1f4d67796e03",
            "author": "",
            "thumbnail": "",
            "description": "FeedForAll helps Realtors and Real Estate companies communicate with clients informing them of newly available properties, and open house announcements. RSS helps to reach a targeted audience and spread the word in an inexpensive, professional manner. <br><br>\nFeeds can be used for:<br><i>Open House Dates<br>\nNew Properties For Sale<br>\nMortgage Rates</i>\n",
            "content": "FeedForAll helps Realtors and Real Estate companies communicate with clients informing them of newly available properties, and open house announcements. RSS helps to reach a targeted audience and spread the word in an inexpensive, professional manner. <br><br>\nFeeds can be used for:<br><i>Open House Dates<br>\nNew Properties For Sale<br>\nMortgage Rates</i>\n",
            "enclosure": [],
            "categories": [
                "Computers/Software/Internet/Site Management/Content Management"
            ]
        },
        {
            "title": "RSS Solutions for Banks / Mortgage Companies",
            "pubDate": "2004-10-19 15:08:57",
            "link": "http://www.feedforall.com/banks.htm",
            "guid": "548e21e2baaba66f6cf56a92d72fa85a",
            "author": "",
            "thumbnail": "",
            "description": "FeedForAll helps <b>Banks, Credit Unions and Mortgage companies</b> communicate with the general public about rate changes in a prompt and professional manner. <br><br>\nUses include:<br><i>Mortgage Rates<br>\nForeign Exchange Rates <br>\nBank Rates<br>\nSpecials</i>\n",
            "content": "FeedForAll helps <b>Banks, Credit Unions and Mortgage companies</b> communicate with the general public about rate changes in a prompt and professional manner. <br><br>\nUses include:<br><i>Mortgage Rates<br>\nForeign Exchange Rates <br>\nBank Rates<br>\nSpecials</i>\n",
            "enclosure": [],
            "categories": [
                "Computers/Software/Internet/Site Management/Content Management"
            ]
        },
        {
            "title": "RSS Solutions for Law Enforcement",
            "pubDate": "2004-10-19 15:08:56",
            "link": "http://www.feedforall.com/law-enforcement.htm",
            "guid": "6e4ab6d2fee3c163f22e07ac8df11421",
            "author": "",
            "thumbnail": "",
            "description": "\n<b>FeedForAll</b> helps Law Enforcement Professionals communicate with the general public and other agencies in a prompt and efficient manner. Using RSS police are able to quickly disseminate urgent and life threatening information. <br><br>\nUses include:<br><i>Amber Alerts<br>\nSex Offender Community Notification <br>\nWeather Alerts <br>\nScheduling <br>\nSecurity Alerts <br>\nPolice Report <br>\nMeetings</i>\n",
            "content": "\n<b>FeedForAll</b> helps Law Enforcement Professionals communicate with the general public and other agencies in a prompt and efficient manner. Using RSS police are able to quickly disseminate urgent and life threatening information. <br><br>\nUses include:<br><i>Amber Alerts<br>\nSex Offender Community Notification <br>\nWeather Alerts <br>\nScheduling <br>\nSecurity Alerts <br>\nPolice Report <br>\nMeetings</i>\n",
            "enclosure": [],
            "categories": [
                "Computers/Software/Internet/Site Management/Content Management"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are incrementing the counter for every property. As it is set to `0` to start with, you should only do that at the end:

```
$json['item'][$i++]['title'] = $title;
$json['item'][$i++]['description'] = $description;
$json['item'][$i++]['pubdate'] = $pubDate;
$json['item'][$i++]['guid'] = $guid;
```

should be:

```
$json['item'][$i]['title'] = $title;
$json['item'][$i]['description'] = $description;
$json['item'][$i]['pubdate'] = $pubDate;
$json['item'][$i]['guid'] = $guid; 
# Increment the counter for the next iteration
$i++;
```

Answer (score 1):

You're incrementing $i each time you add a new item. Try this:

```
$json['item'][$i++] = array(
  'title' => $title,
  'description' => $description,
  'pubdate' => $pubDate,
  'guid' => $guid,
);
```

Or:

```
$json['item'][$i]['title'] = $title;
$json['item'][$i]['description'] = $description;
$json['item'][$i]['pubdate'] = $pubDate;
$json['item'][$i]['guid'] = $guid;  
$i++;
```